# Navigate from one embedded UIViewController in swiftUI to another embedded UIViewcontroller in swift UI

Tags: swiftui, uiviewcontroller, navigationview, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I have a UIViewController which is embedded in swiftUI View

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView(overlayShow: OverlayShow())
    }
}

struct OnboardingWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var overlayShow: OverlayShow
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ReturnSomthing {
        let controller = ReturnSomthing(shareConfig: onboardingConfig)
        controller.showOverlay = overlayShow
        return controller
    }

   func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ReturnSomthing, context: Context) {
    
    }

    public typealias UIViewControllerType = ReturnSomthing
}
```

I want to be able to Navigate directly from SwiftUI to another SwiftUI view with embedded UIViewController
SO, I did on a view of SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var overlayShow: OverlayShow = OverlayShow()
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: OverlayView(overlay:     LoadingUnknownOverlayViewContainer(description: "it is spinning :0", designModel:     LoadingOverlayDesignModel(type: .unknown))), isActive: $overlayShow.isShowingOverlay) {
                OnboardingWrapper(overlayShow: overlayShow) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the condition for navigation to be active is the `overlayShow.isShowingOverlay` is `true`. this variable is controlled in UIViewController with an `ObservableObject`.

the problem is that no matter the value of `overlayShow.isShowingOverlay` wherever I tap the first UIViewController which is `OnboardingWrapper` the navigation is activated and goes to the next page.

To be more clear I post a screen recording. [image]
Please how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are seeing OnboardingWrapper and when you click on it, you are seeing OverlayView.
Perhaps this would help:

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            OnboardingWrapper(overlayShow: overlayShow)
            NavigationLink(destination: OverlayView(
                overlay:LoadingUnknownOverlayViewContainer(
                    description: "it is spinning :0",
                    designModel: LoadingOverlayDesignModel(type: .unknown))),
                    isActive: $overlayShow.isShowingOverlay) {
                EmptyView() 
            }
        }
    }
```

OnboardingWrapper will appear, then when overlayShow.isShowingOverlay is true, the OverlayView should be presented.